# What's the difference between Java RE download with an 'S' and without it?

Tags: java

There are two different downloads for Java 7 offline Windows x86 installation. One with an 's' and one without. I've tried looking around but can't seem to find what differentiates the two?

jre-7u1-windows-i586-s.exe
jre-7u1-windows-i586.exe

Can anyone shed some light on the subject, as there seems to be nothing on the Java download page explaining what the 's' is for!

**Edit:** Snapshot adding

[image]

Comment: I only see one version on the following page (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u1-download-513651.html) - what download page are you on?

Comment: @normalocity check [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-7u1-download-513652.html)

Comment: Hm, I don't see it listed there either. It's possible the page is customized to the browser locale. I'm coming from the US - maybe the page your seeing is for another country/customized to another locale?

Comment: I don't see it: I see one x86 version  and one x86_64 version, obviously marked as such; there's no file named jre-7u1-windows-i586-s.exe . Perhaps the offered choices depend on your download location.

Comment: @Ernest check the snapshot. I can see it from India and from Ubuntu

Comment: He's asking about the JRE, not the JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-7u1-download-513652.html

Comment: ~.23 MB is the main difference I can see from the screen shot! :-)

Comment: may be something related to `Source` from `S`. not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -s version of the installer is their sponsored version that includes an installer for a 3rd-party toolbar or product.
If you don't install the 3rd-party product, the resulting JRE from jre-7u1-windows-i586-s.exe and jre-7u1-windows-i586.exe is identical.

Answer (score 1):

It's the "Standalone installer". Why they only have it for the x86 version? No idea.

You don't need it unless you have problems with the online or offline installer.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of your answer. What is the difference between a "Standalone installer" and a "Offline installer"? Are there any related link/documentation about this?

Comment: I've noticed this for the jre6's even. Still not sure what the difference is. You can find the "-s" version on java.com and one without the -s at orcale's site (where you would download the JDK). There is a minor size different, so they are clearly different installs. I'm not sure what the difference between "standalone" and "offline" is supposed to be myself, that would really help matters.